# New norm with strictly coarser induced topolgy

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ be an infinite dimensional normed space.

> Does there alway exist a norm $|||\cdot|||$ on $V$ which induces a strictly **coarser** topology than $\|\cdot\|$?

I know, that there is always a norm  which induces a strictly **finer** topolgy: We can  choose an unbounded linear functional $l:V\to\mathbb K$ and define a new norm as $\|\cdot\|+|l(\cdot)|$. Then

$$\text{Id}:(V,\|\cdot\|+|l(\cdot)|)\to(V,\|\cdot\|)$$

is bounded with unbounded inverse, so $\|\cdot\|+|l(\cdot)|$ induces a strictly finer topolgy. But what about the converse?